# Help with graphing Functions

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have a exam question which is as follows

[image]

I can not find what these types of questions are called when I search Google nothing similar comes up.

Any links or videos or just the name of these problems would be appreciated.

My values seem very obscure and I know they are incorrect for example the first point in the table I has coordinates

**(-8,-555)**

Comment: Why does the first value contain $-8$? You have $-2\le x\le 2$.

Comment: @Andrei : I got -8 becuase I had .5(-2)^3 = -8. I am not sure what to do with this cubic ad the interval is .5x^3.

Comment: I think that extra $x^3$ is a mistake. Also, please format your equations, using Mathjax. Mostly it means  putting `$` signs around the formula. So `$x^3$` will render as $x^3$. Also note that $0.5(-2)^3=-4$

Comment: I will do in the future thanks you may of saved me hours of frustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Plot of the graph by Abdul Halim]

Plot Of the graph $y=x^3-x^2-2x+5$,$ -2\leq x \leq 2 $

Comment: The construction of table of (a) is possible by yourself.

Comment: Cool thanks I got it now my graph looks the same this is great I feel alot more cofident now on passing my exams thanks :)

Comment: You should say which software you have used (Desmos ? Geogebra) in order that next time the OP is able to do it by him/herself ; if it is Desmos, including the the way equations are written brings a supplementary understanding.